# Is DOMElement renderable?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a way to check if an Element is renderable ?

for example, i want some method to return `true` on `br` `a` `div` `body` `html` etc

but to return `false` on `head` `style` `script` etc

i tried `if(!el.style) return false;` but it seems even `head` and `style` have `.style`

is it at all possible or should i just make a list of renderable tagnames ?

Comment: what's your definition of "renderable"?

Comment: @endyourif an element that can have position (X/Y) on page to be honest ;P thats all i need. too bad `<br/>` s are broken (offsetXXX = 0)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a simple solution. Check which elements have `display: none` at creation.

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/web5me/n9JfR/1/)

```
function isDefaultVisible(domElement) {
    var el = document.createElement(domElement.tagName);
    return window.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue('display') != 'none';
}
```

Comment: nice, this would work flawlessly with going thru stylesheet rules to filter elements hidden by page stylesheets ;)

Comment: it wont work without heavy modifications, my method is better at the moment :) if i have time to expand on your solution ill accept and edit in my version

Comment: The way I understand your question my solution does exactly what you want. Please explain if I'm wrong...

Comment: how about a menu that shows on hover ? it has display:none; but not ALLWAYS a rare case if the selector is the tag itself but still not 100% working :P

Comment: The test works for all common use cases, eg. inline `display: none` applied with jQuery `.hide()`, classes applied for hiding, because it creates a fresh element.

If you do a global reset, eg. `li {display: none;}` which makes no sense anyway, the test still returns the correct, new answer: `false`.

 If you really absolutely want to know the browser defaults you can do the test in an otherwise empty iframe. That should be 'fun'. =)

Answer (score 1):

All elements can be rendered. It really depends on the browser's default stylesheet.
Refer to this great article for more information:

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-hidden-elements

Comment: I just noticed that :P Guess what i ment is "elements it is SANE to render" :P

Answer (score 0):

```
function isElementRenderable(el){
    if(el.nodeType != 1) return false;
    if(el instanceof HTMLHeadElement || el instanceof HTMLLinkElement ||
       el instanceof HTMLTitleElement|| el instanceof HTMLMetaElement ||
       el instanceof HTMLBaseElement || el instanceof HTMLStyleElement||
       el instanceof HTMLScriptElement)
    return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: These interfaces don't exist in older Internet Explorer versions. Simple `/^(head|link|title|meta|base|style|script)$/i.test(el.nodeName)` is more readable and works everywhere.